# trouble getting .on function to work as it is supposed to

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-on, jquery-delegate

I have an html page with the following html:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="pagination">
        <a href=''>blah</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Going to a page that has the following js doesn't return any alert:

```
$("#content").on(".pagination a", "click", function(event){
    alert("alert message")
})
```

Going to the same page with this js does work:

```
$("#content .pagination a".on("click", function() {
    alert("alert message")
})
```

why? in the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) API the first one is supposed to bind the delegated functionality to the content id and the second is supposed to bind it to the a tag within the content id, yet the first one doesn't happen.

**What is wrong with the way I'm using `on()` function to delegate the click event?**

Comment: I changed the asd to something else, happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.on()` is different from `.delegate()`

Correct syntax for `.on()` is -

```
on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
```

You need this :

```
$("#content").on("click",".pagination a", function(event){
    alert("asdasdasd")
})
```

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#content").on("click",".pagination a", function(event){
    alert("asdasdasd")
})
```

Switch to the above definition